# jquery using $.deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm using jQuery `$.when` function to synchronize two `$.getJSON` asynchronous calls I have. Merging the data from both calls now works fine, however I want to return the contents of the merge , which is an array of jQuery objects.

I'm trying to achieve this using a `$.when` function wrapped around another function which contains the code where I synchronize my asynchronous calls. My code looks like this:

```
 $.fn.getResultFromMergedJsonCalls = function(params){
    $.when( 
    $.fn.jsonCall1(params), $.fn.jsonCAll2(params)
     ).then(function(){
       var mergedData = mergeResults(resultOfJsonCAll1,resultOfJsonCAll2)
           return mergedData;
    });
   };
)
```

How can I return the contents of the `mergedData` array to a calling function , i know the nature of the asynchronous calls is causing this behavior so i just need a pattern that solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can't. It's asynchronous. You have to process the result inside the callback you pass to `.then`, or pass it to a function called from inside the callback.

Comment: You usually don't call `$.fn` functions directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a callback function to getResultsFromMergedJsonCalls, then invoke the callback from the `then` handler. For example:

```
$.fn.getResultFromMergedJsonCalls = function(params, success){
$.when( 
$.fn.jsonCall1(params), $.fn.jsonCAll2(params)
 ).then(function(){
   if (success) {
       var mergedData = mergeResults(resultOfJsonCAll1,resultOfJsonCAll2);
       success(mergedData);
});
```

};

The caller of getResultsFromMergedJsonCalls of course must implement a suitable function to pass as that new, callback argument.

Answer (score 2):

That's asynchronous; you can't return it.

Instead, you need to pass the value back using a callback.